# What are the minimum settings for Vespa's YQL userInput to work?

Tags: vespa

I'm trying to understand how to make a userInput() work, with the minimum of settings.
I could not retrieve results for keyword "product", even with "product 1" in some document titles.
I simplified the query and settings to the bare minimum. Filters and aggregations work fine.

The field definition, without any ranking, fieldset, ...:

```
field wpsolr_title type string {
  indexing: summary | index
}
```

The field content in a document:
[image]

The query:

```
{"userQuery":"product","yql":"select * from wpsolr1 where (userInput(@userQuery))"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not specifying the index, terms in the user query will by default search `default` so the parsed query here becomes

```
select * from wpsolr1 where weakAnd(default contains "product")
```

You need to **either** put the fields you want users to search by default into a fieldset called "default":

```
fieldset default { # in schema, outside the document block
    fields: wpsolr_title, my_other_field, ...
}
```

**or** specify the default field or fieldset to be used for the user query:

```
select * from wpsolr1 where {defaultIndex:"wpsolr_title"}userInput(@userQuery)
```

**Tip**: You can always see the query that is produced by passing tracelevel=1 as a HTTP parameter.

Comment: As stated, a fieldset is indeed mandatory in my use case. I failed to mention that my document type was inherited from a parent document type. In the parent schema file, I defined a fieldset, mistakenly thinking that field sets are also inherited.